# DbContext doesn't load data properly from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a .NET application where users can create/edit their filters and a second console application which runs as background task and applies their filters.

I extended `Application` use class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Filters = new List<FilterData>();
    }

    [SqlDefaultValue(DefaultValue = 0)]
    public long Credit { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FilterData> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

My console application creates a `DbContext` and tries to use `Filters` property:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContextEx>()
            .UseSqlServer(@"connection string....")
            .Options;

    ApplicationDbContextEx context = new ApplicationDbContextEx(contextOptions);

    foreach (var user in context.Users.ToList())
    { 
        // Filters 
        Debug.Assert(user.Filters != null, "weird because we have filters in db");      
    }
}
```

My problem is that `user.Filters` is always null even when there are valid filters in the database.

I would guess it is issue with DbContext creation.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Are the filters actually linked to the users that are being used in that loop?

Comment: You are using Assert.Debug in a foreach loop, a more accurate assertion would be something like:  `Debug.Assert(context.Users.All(x => x.Filters == null),"weird because we have filters in db");`

Comment: Debug.Assert is not present in my real code I add it only to show what is wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined the relationship using either convention, attributes or the FluentAPI? Try using `Include`:

```
foreach (var user in context.Users.Include(a => a.Filters).ToList())
{
}
```

Comment: Hi yes I used fluentAPI :  
  builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().
                HasMany(u => u.Filters).
                WithOne(u => u.ApplicationUser);

Comment: But you haven't used `Include`.  Related data is not loaded by default, otherwise you might load your entire database.